# Changing Color Space from RGB to HSV after segmentation (OpenCv Python)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am segmenting an image and then converting it into HSV format. But after converting it into HSV and separating out each of the channels, the granularity of the segmented region is lost. Following is the segmentation code.

```
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "C:/Users/Intern/Desktop/dataset/rust images/"
files_test = [f for f in listdir(path+ 'Input/') if isfile(join(path+ 'Input/', f))]
for img_name in files_test:
    img = cv2.imread(path + "Input/" + img_name)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (7, 7), 0)
    adapt_thresh_im = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 20)
    max_thresh, thresh_im = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    thresh = cv2.bitwise_or(adapt_thresh_im, thresh_im)
    kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)
    sure_bg = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations=2)
    img[sure_bg == 0] = [0,0,0]
    cv2.imwrite(path + "Segmented/" + img_name, img)
```

Following is the input image.[image: Input]

Following is the corresponding output.

[image: Output]
Now, In a new program I try to read this output and convert it into HSV format. Following is the code.

```
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np

path = "C:/Users/Intern/Desktop/dataset/rust images/"
files_test = [f for f in listdir(path+ "Segmented/") if isfile(join(path+ "Segmented/", f))]
for img_name in files_rust:
    img = cv2.imread(path + "Segmented/" + img_name)
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    print img_hsv.shape
    h, s, v = cv2.split(img_hsv)
    cv2.imshow("hsv image", s)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Following is the output after converting into HSV.
[image: Output]

We can observe that compared to the original one the granularity of the black spaces has reduced. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Photograph taken from [4](http://www.istockphoto.com/in?esource=SEM_IS_GO_IN_Photograph_Stock_Head_EN_Broad&kw=IN_Photograph_Broad_%2Bstock+%2Bphotograph_b&kwid=s_43700009930191235_dc&pcrid=92932651095&esource=SEM_IS_GO_IN_Photograph_Stock_Head_EN_Broad&kw=IN_Photograph_Broad_%2Bstock+%2Bphotograph_b&kwid=s_43700009930191235_dc&pcrid=92932651095&gclid=CjwKEAjwsLTJBRCvibaW9bGLtUESJAC4wKw1eKFKhcVHU0WEuvrrEG2u6iz1RSVSRYm_0rJoXIIMjRoC3Zvw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: Post the images in the question above. The linked images may not be accessible over time.

Comment: Why you have to applied filters and preprocess the image if you only need to have the image in HSV color space?

Comment: That's JPEG for ya. Don't use lossy compression, especially not for intermediate results.

Comment: @thewaywewere, Thanks for the suggestion! I have made appropriate modifications. I could solve the problem!

Comment: @SatwikBhamidi Geat to hear you have fixed the problem. I will put my suggestion as an answer for your acceptance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code showed you applied `GaussianBlur()`, `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` and `cv2.morphologyEx()`, all those filtering would likely make the details lost in some degree in the resulted image.

If you need to convert color space from BGR to HSV, `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`, then you may just do minimal preprocessing to reduce the distortion before converting the image to HSV, and before you further any processing in `HSV` color space.